# Input Mask Javascript com decimal negativo

Tags: javascript

Peguei este código aqui do fórum, porém estou com dúvidas em relação ao uso com números negativos.

O usuário está precisando digitar 1° o sinal negativo e depois os números.
Certos resultados serão negativos outros não, por isso precisava de uma forma que o usuário conseguisse digitar primeiro o sinal e depois os números.

Segue código:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$('.numerico').mask('#.##0', {
     reverse: true,
     translation: {
        '#': {
            pattern: /-|\d/,
            recursive: true
        }
     },
     onChange: function(value, e) {
        e.target.value = value.replace(/(?!^)-/g, '').replace(/^,/, '').replace(/^-,/, '-');
     }
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na mascara precisa ter a identificação do sinal como opcional e isso é identificado com a letra `N` na configuração `translation`, e dessa forma tem a opção de digitar números com o sinal de negativo, ***exemplo***:

```js
$('.numerico').mask('N#.##0', {
    translation: {
        'N': {
            pattern: /[-]/,
            optional: true
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.13.4/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="numerico" />
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Virgilio, deu super certo com este código. \m/